# npm ERR @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.0-placeholder-for-preset-env.2

Tags: npm

$ npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.0-placeholder-for-preset-env.2.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@babel/preset-env'

I want install @babel/preset-env
but, i get the error npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.0-placeholder-for-preset-env.2